# Remove BackEnd character in a 'NSString'

Tags: ios, objective-c, replace, nsstring, character

I'm facing a problem when I try to remove a character in a 'NSString'. The character is a backend (\n).

My 'NSString' is for example like this :

```
My text is
also in a second line
```

And I want to get all in one line like this :

```
My text is also in a second line
```

The problem is I don't know how to change this...
I tried to locate the '\n' characters with a loop :

```
for (int delete = 0; delete < myString.length; delete++)
{
    if ([myString characterAtIndex:delete] == 10)
    {
        [myString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(delete,0) withString:@" "];
    }
}
```

Or things like :

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@" "];
```

(I see that \r could be the backend in a nslog...)

Nothings work..

Thank you for your help in advance !

Comment: Did you try `myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];`?

Comment: `\n` is not a "backend". It is a "newline" character.

Comment: OP's words were: "The character is a backend (\n)."

Comment: Looks like working... :)     \n is not a backend ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

is correct.

If it doesn't work, then the assumption that there is a combination of "\" and "n" characters is wrong.

Do not use `NSLog`. `NSLog` already applies carriage returns to the string. Instead put a breakpoint on the line where we call `stringByReplacing...` and then hover over the `myString`. Wait a second or two and you will see the "original unformatted content"...this way you can check what you are really trying to replace..